# leave the <select> object expanded after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am not sure if it is possible but I would like to leave the HTML `<select>` object expended using JavaScript, JQuery after the selection. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

What I want is that; if user selects more option from select list, I will append some more options to select element and leave it open. If user selects something other than more option, I will collapse the list. I can get a hold of other functionality but only problem here is to keep the select element open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible directly.  You'd have to implement something that looked and worked like a native `<select>` but which also had the feature you want.

*edit* — check Mr. Kling's answer; there might be a way to make that work, sort-of.

Comment: yeah, but @Felix Kling's answer is not what I want. you way looks like the only way so far

Answer (score 1):

You could come very close with this:

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).children().length);
});
```

The [`size` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select#Attributes) specifies how many options to display (default is `0`).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/pPKwB/)

You might have to make some tests whether this works in every (recent) browser. But imo this would be better than trying to simulate a select box (screen readers, etc).

Comment: I think that browsers only pay attention to "size" when "multiple" is true, but this is a possible idea - you could "fake" the single-select behavior, maybe ...

Comment: hmm, gonna give it a try on jsfiddle. hang in there.

Comment: @Pointy: Works in Chrome so far. But the documentation also says: *Browsers are not required to present a select elements as a scrolled list box.* So it might not work everywhere...

Comment: Oops I was apparently wrong about the "multiple" thing; weird, I was just messing with that the other day ...  live and learn.

Comment: ooooww :s it makes it listbox :s not the thing I was looking for but still an option. +1 for that.

Comment: @tugberk: You might have to make some tests whether this works in every (recent) browser. But this would be better than trying to simulate a select box (screen readers, etc).

Comment: @Felix also another thing, it messes with the style. here, have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/GHWmF/2/

Comment: @tugberk: Well, what do you want exactly? Should the option list stay open and cover other elements? That does not seem to be useful.... or should it only stay open until the user clicks outside of it?

Comment: @Felix well, what I want is that; if user selects ***more*** option from select list, I will append some more options to select element and leave it open. If user selects something other than ***more*** option, I will collapse the list. I can get a hold of other functionality but only problem here is to keep the select element open.

Answer (score 0):

You can not expand the select element with JavaScript. You can use select multiple, but that is probably not what you want.